# Android Detect Pressing On Power Key

Tags: android

My Application needs to know if the screen went off due to timeout or the user clicked the power button.

I decided to check if the power button was pressed.
I read some Q&A here and came up with this :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {    

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            Log.w("Test", "Power button down detected");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            Log.w("Test", "Power button up detected");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also added this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY"/>
```

This doesn't work, it doesn't print the log.

Answer (score 3):

Try to yseing from `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        //DO HERE
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        //DO HERE
    }
}
}
```

and your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: How can i differ between screen going off due to timeout or due to button clicked?

Comment: I've insert the Log into this code but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

The onKeyDown method, no longer detects the single Power Key click. It does however detect the long press. Here's a very simple trick to capture it, and to differentiate from other buttons and other user's activities that would bring the app to the background.

```
       PwrKeyShortPress = true; // set the default value in your class
        ....
         ....

       @Override
        public void onUserLeaveHint(){
            PwrKeyShortPress = false;
            super.onUserLeaveHint();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            if (PwrKeyShortPress) {
              // Do something for single Power Key click.      
            }
            PwrKeyShortPress = true;
            super.onStop();
        }
```

Comment: There's lots of things that would break this code.  For example, an incoming phone call wouldn't trigger onUserLeaveHint.  This case is even in the documentation for the function.

Answer (score 1):

go this way

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Power Button pressed
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

EDIT

you can listen to the screen ON/OFF this way

```
          if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                    //do something 
            }

            else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                    //do something else
            }
```