# How I Detect long press of power button android 11

Tags: android, mobile-application, mobile-app-tracker

How I detect long press of power button android Programmatically.

I try many of the codes but not working. Pls Help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832380/android-detect-pressing-on-power-key

Comment: You don't.  That's handled by the system.  Extreme long press (10s or longer to reset the phone) isn't even handled by the OS its handled by hardware.

Comment: Also nothing in the link @DhruvSakariya linked actually works.  Some of them are partical  workarounds, but all of them break under various cases.

Comment: @DhruvSakariya : - I try this link codes but not detect long press.

Comment: @GabeSechan : - This is possible in Many Security Apps. I try to implement in my project but i cannot find any solution

Comment: did you find the solution @SafalBhatia? please suggest your thought .

Comment: NO find any solutions